# NPM run-script init-cloudsql skipping user prompt

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm

I'm just starting here so sorry in advance if this seems obvious,
I've been getting myself accustomed with the appengine back-end and am following Google's bookshelf example as a start.

Everything was going okay until I run the NPM run-script init-cloudsql command and for some reason after I enter the host IP of my db the cmd skips the user prompt and asks me for the password. Then it tried to launch the script with an anonymous user.

I'm following the instructions as described, I get no errors in the previous steps.

Below is the log of my run-script:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\barda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run-script',
1 verbose cli   'init-cloudsql' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.0
3 info using node@v4.2.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'preinit-cloudsql', 'init-cloudsql', 'postinit-cloudsql' ]
5 info lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~preinit-cloudsql: nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~preinit-cloudsql: no script for preinit-cloudsql, continuing
7 info lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~init-cloudsql: nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~init-cloudsql: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~init-cloudsql: PATH: C:\Users\barda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\nodejs-getting-started-2-structured-data\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\;C:\Users\barda\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\barda\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
10 verbose lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~init-cloudsql: CWD: C:\nodejs-getting-started-2-structured-data
11 silly lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~init-cloudsql: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node books/model-cloudsql.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~init-cloudsql: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0~init-cloudsql: Failed to exec init-cloudsql script
14 verbose stack Error: nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0 init-cloudsql: `node books/model-cloudsql.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\barda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\barda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\nodejs-getting-started-2-structured-data
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\barda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "init-cloudsql"
19 error node v4.2.2
20 error npm  v3.5.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0 init-cloudsql: `node books/model-cloudsql.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0 init-cloudsql script 'node books/model-cloudsql.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the nodejs-getting-started package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node books/model-cloudsql.js
23 error You can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls nodejs-getting-started
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you include the output from the console as well, which shows the actual prompts and error output (with the login details redacted of course)?

Comment: For some background, I do not get this error when following the steps at https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql (Run the app on your local computer), but I do get an error if I use incorrect host / login details or have incorrect access configured on my CloudSQL instance (eg. disallowing access from the local IP).

Comment: thanks guys for answering, i finally managed to fix the issue by running the script in the webstorm ! i guess it's an issue with the windows 10 CMD....
Cheers